# Can a linear transformation be expressed by constants?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$.

$$T
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Is T a valid transformation, now that the 5th coordianate is a constant or does it have to be expressed by $x_1, x_2, x_3$ or $x_4$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The function $T$ is not a linear transformation, as given, since the zero vector is not in its range.